# Using ggplot (or just plot) to track house price appreciation over time in a multi-line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to figure this out for days but to no avail

I'm trying to show that a subset of 50-or-so houses along a particular bit of coast have appreciated since the 1990s. The data I have to work with is patchy, as in, each house has only sold between 2-5 times from 1983-2023.

I've made a spreadsheet where the columns are years (1983, 1984, 1985, 1986 and so on) and the rows are particular properties. I want to make a multi-line plot, with each line representing one property. I know it will look like a bit of a mess because each property doesn't have that many datapoints (as in, times its been sold), but the fact that they've all appreciated should be clear.

I want the x-axis to be the years, and the y axis to be the price they sold for. Each line should be a property.

I've been trawling forums but I'm at a loss

Any help would be massively appreciated :>

I've tried ggplot, but get stuck early on. I don't know how to define the x=, because I want the x axis to be all the columns (because each column in my .csv file is a year).

I tried doing it manually too.
When I do this, I get a small version of what I'm after but with fake numbers and years:

```
x  <- c(1990,2000,2005,2010, 2015,2020) #FAKE YEARS 
y1 <- c(NA,101,105,367, NA, NA) #FAKE PRICES. , y1 is one house. 
y2 <- c(1000, 568, 6237, 87, NA, NA) #FAKE PRICES HOUSE TWO, SIMPLY WRITE NA FOR MISSING VALUES
y3 <- c(3,6,12,14,17,15)
```

```
plot(x, y1, type="o", col = "blue", pch="o", ylab="y", lty=10)
points(x, y2, col="red", pch="o")
lines(x, y3, col="green", lty=2)
```

But when I tried inputting my actual data, the dotted lines disappear, and I just get dots showing on the graph:

```
years <- c(1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023)
xx <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 330000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 599000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
xxx <- c(NA,    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 325000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 621000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 704000, NA, NA, NA, 100000000,  NA, NA, NA, 100000000, NA,  NA)

plot(years, xx, type="o", col = "blue", pch="o", ylab="y",lty="solid")

points(years, xxx, col="red", pch="o")
lines(years, xxx, col="green", lty=2)
```

I've attached a picture of my spreadsheet, but It's only a corner of it. The actual spreadsheet has 57 rows and 40 columns (til the year 2023).

If there's a way to do it with ggplot2 that'd be great, but if I have to manually type out my spreadsheet using vectors that's okay too

Comment: You don't need to type out vectors manually if you have the data stored in a CSV file. You can use `read.csv` to read the data into R as a dataframe. Can you share some of the data using `dput()` after  you've read in the CSV file? If you want to use {ggplot2} you'll likely need to use `pivot_longer()` to put your data into long format.

Comment: Are you trying to join the points while skipping NA values?

Answer (score 1):

You should put your data into a data frame for plotting with `ggplot`. It would also be useful to pivot the data into long format, which means having the data frame formatted so that you have a column for the year, a column labelling which house the row refers to, and a column for the house price. Having data in this format makes it much easier to work with and plot, and is very easy using `tidyr::pivot_longer`

However, your main problem is that if you are drawing a line plot, the line gets broken where there are `NA` values. Any year surrounded by `NA` values has nothing to connect to, and therefore is missing entirely from your plot. To get round this, you can perform *linear interpolation* on the missing values. The function `pracma::interp1` can do this for you.

Having the data in this format will make it easy to create a ggplot with lots of options to fully customize the appearance of your graphic.

Here's a fully reproducible example. I have modified your example somewhat for clarity because the last couple of values for `xxx` completely dwarf the scale of the rest of the plot. If these are genuine, you might want to think about a logarithmic y axis.

```r
years <- (1983:2023)[-20]
xx <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 330000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 599000, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
xxx <- c(NA,    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 325000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
         NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 621000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 704000, 
         NA, NA, NA, 1000000,  NA, NA, NA, 1000000, NA,  NA)

library(tidyverse)

data.frame(years, xx, xxx) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-years) %>%
  mutate(is_real = !is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(value = pracma::interp1(years, value, years, "linear")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(years, value, colour = name)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE, linewidth = 2, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(is_real), na.rm = TRUE, size = 4) +
  scale_color_manual("House", values = c("deepskyblue4", "orange")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

If we use the data posted in the question, we could use a log scale to avoid losing detail in the lower values. To do this, we would change our `scale_y_continuous` call to

```r
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, trans = "log10")
```

resulting in

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-07-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Ah this is incredible, thank you so much :')

Comment: I'm using your code now, thank you again, it's working perfectly so far